# Identifying the line where a function was invoked

Tags: php, sql, debugging, line

Having a repetitive code like so:

```
$SQL = " INSERT INTO ... ";

mysql_query($SQL, $conexion);
$error = mysql_error();

if($_ADM['id_user']==1) {
    if( ! empty($error)) {
        $debug = array(
                    'message' => "SQL Error in news_edit module.",
                    'line'    => '177',
                    'error'   => $error,
                    'SQL'     => $SQL
                );
        exit(print_r($debug));
    }
}
```

This is a common code, that repeats its self every time `$SQL` changes. What I'm trying to achieve is a way to debug if any error occurs and as I you can see, I have the `line` parameter which contains the number line where last `mysql_query` was executed, but I have to type that manually and every time I add code before it, the `line` parameters needs to be changed with the new line value.

Is there any way of identifying where was last time `mysql_query` executed? Any other way of improving the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `debug_backtrace` function.
Check the manual for specs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Oh, after reading again the documentation I think this could be a solution. Create a common debug function with the `debug_backtrace()` function inside, and invoke the function on error. Tnx

Comment: No problem, I use it for debugging, so I know it's great :)

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
'line'=> __LINE__,
```

its a magic constant which displays the current line of the file..